# How to return derived class with C# generics

Tags: c#, nbuilder

I am trying to generate some test data using NBuilder for automation for all the classes that extends a base class wherein each class will have different fields.

Here is my code:

```
public interface Interface
{
    T method<T>() where T : BaseClass;
}

public class DrivedClass: BaseClass,Interface
{
    public T method<T>() where T : BaseClass
    {
        var derviedObj = Builder<DrivedClass>.CreateNew().Build();

        return derviedObj;
    }
}
```

`return derviedObj` giving error cannot implicity convert `derviedObj` to `T`

Comment: Since the method uses an open type T, you have to return an instance of such type rather than instance of a concrete type DerivedClass.

Comment: please see my answer.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not really familiar with nbuilder, but it looks like you could try something like this:

```
public class DrivedClass: BaseClass,Interface
{
    public T method<T>() where T : BaseClass
    {
        var derviedObj = Builder<T>.CreateNew().Build();

        return derviedObj;
    }
}
```

Or this, if that's what you're really after:

```
public class DrivedClass: BaseClass,Interface
{
    public T method<T>() where T : BaseClass
    {
        var derviedObj = Builder<DrivedClass>.CreateNew().Build();

        return derviedObj as T;
    }
}
```

Then you will get `T`, but there's really no chance of knowing that it will succeed. What happens when you add another implementation that doesn't inherit `DrivedClass`?

```
public class MoreDrivedClass : BaseClass, FooInterface
{

}
```

Then this cast will fail:

```
var drivedClass = new DrivedClass();
var foo = drivedClass.method<MoreDrivedClass>();
```

Then you will not be able to cast `DrivedClass` to `MoreDrivedClass`. `Foo` will be null.

Answer (score 1):

The method can't return `DerivedClass` because there is no way to know if `T` is that class or some other one:

```
SomeOtherDerived v = (new DrivedClass()).method<SomeOtherDerived>();
```

It is not clear what you trying to achieve, possibly something like following  sample:

```
public interface Interface<T> where T : BaseClass
{
    T method();
}

public class DrivedClass: BaseClass,Interface<DerivedClass>
{
  public DerivedClass method()
  {
      DerivedClass derviedObj = Builder<DrivedClass>.CreateNew().Build();
      return derviedObj ;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with Activator.CreateInstance.

```
public class DrivedClass: BaseClass,Interface
{
  public T method<T>() where T : BaseClass
    {
      var derviedObj = Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T));
      return (T)derviedObj ; 

    }
}


 DrivedClass drOb = new DrivedClass ();
 var v = drOb.method<desiredType_T>();
```